# when extract keras model feature does not get the all feature labels

Tags: python-3.x, keras, deep-learning

```
inputs =[input_1,input_3]
outputs =[output_1,output_3]
combine = concatenate(outputs)

output = Dense(400,activation='sigmoid',name ='dense_1')(combine)
output = Dense(num_classes,activation='softmax')(output)

model = Model(inputs,[output])
```

I use a keras multi input classifier model i extract the dense1 layer        features but when i extract the labels of the layer i expect 10 class but i got some time 7 class or sometime i got 9 class why i got this type of output